# What is the name of a game in which if you both choose the same, you will lose, otherwise, one will win?

Tags: game-theory

I am familiar with games like Prisoners Dilemma and Chicken game. However, I could not find out the name of this specific game that I believe should have interesting properties. This game has this payoff matrix:
[image]

Do you know whether this game has a famous name?

Comment: I suppose this is an (anti-)coordination game. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordination_game

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer Would you mind writing that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Done :) ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer: This is an instance of an (anti-)coordination game. See this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordination_game).